I'm unable to delete the current line and print in the same line again
I want to delete the output in the current line and then print in the same line again in Python. I'm basically creating a 25s timer with the format:
Time remaining: 
The code that I've written works on my phone (I'm using Pydroid 3), but it does not run on my computer(Spyder 5). The computer just prints line by line like
Time remaining:25
Time remaining:24...and so on till 0.
I've tried many times, but it still doesn't work. Please help me with this. This is the code I've written:
import time

x=25

for i in range(20,-1,-1):
    if(x==0):
        print("\033[1A"+"Time up!"+"\033[K")
        break

    print("\033[1A"+"Time remaining: "+str(x)+"\033[K")
    time.sleep(1)
    x=x-1


Add the flush=True option to your print() calls.

I don't recognize the sequences in use -- the easy way to send the cursor to the beginning of the same line is to use '\r', though to do that you also need to suppress the automatic '\n' that print() adds by setting end=''.

@Barmar, ...the OP would need flush=True if they were setting end='' and were subject to default line buffering, but they aren't suppressing the default newline, so I don't see why the lack of flush=True would be causing their immediate problem (yet).
